# SyntaxError: JSON .parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: syntax-error, geojson

I imported GeoJSON to my map, but my browser shows me the following error message:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

[image]

(clickable)

This is my script :

```js
< !doctype html >
  < html lang = "en" >
  < head >
  < link rel = 'stylesheet'
href = 'css/ol.css' >
  < style > #map {
    height: 100 % ;
    width: 100 % ;
  } < /style>
    <title>OpenLayers 3 example</title >
  < script src = "build/ol.js"
type = "text/javascript" > < /script>
  </head >
  < body >
  < h1 > My Map < /h1>
    <div id="map"></div >
  < script type = "text/javascript" >


  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      }),




      new ol.layer.Vector({
        title: 'added Layer',
        source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
          projection: 'EPSG:4326',
          url: 'gjson/test.geojson'
        })
      })
    ],

    view: new ol.View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 2

    })
  }); < /script>
  </body >
< /html>
```

Where I made an error? I don't know how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Unrelated, but why do you have all the spaces inside the tags, e.g., `< head >` instead of `<head>`?

Comment: editor in webside created spaces.  " POST json file"  what is it mean ...sorry I am beginner mainly I work in example from ol3